# wget rotated backup problem

Tags: backup, wget

I'm calling `wget` 1.11.4 as follows

```
$ wget -nd -S -N --backups=4 -r --no-parent --reject="index.html*" -e robots=off <url>
```

to repeatedly download all files from a server. My problem is, existing files won't get a rolled backup. Or only up to 1 file. So in the end there exists only 2 files, `myfile` and `myfile.1`. There is never a `myfile.2`.

Why is that? I specifically told `wget` to make 4 backup files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me. --backups is a new option, for example my RHEL6.5 machines do not have it (wget 1.12), and my local Fedora machine does have it (wget 1.14).

Have you tried a simple test without the other options? This is what works for me:

```
>mkdir test; cd test

>wget -q --backups=4 http://ddg.gg/
>ls
index.html

>wget -q --backups=4 http://ddg.gg/
>ls
index.html  index.html.1

>wget -q --backups=4 http://ddg.gg/
>ls
index.html  index.html.1  index.html.2

>wget -q --backups=4 http://ddg.gg/
>ls
index.html  index.html.1  index.html.2  index.html.3

>wget -q --backups=4 http://ddg.gg/
>ls
index.html  index.html.1  index.html.2  index.html.3  index.html.4

>wget -q --backups=4 http://ddg.gg/
>ls
index.html  index.html.1  index.html.2  index.html.3  index.html.4
```

Comment: yes, you're right. It's working with a different version of wget. Your simple case doesn't event work for wget 1.11.4. So it's probably a bug in wget. I'm trying to upgrade and report back. thx for the hint.

Comment: I installed wget 1.15 and it's working now. ;)